# TypeError: User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_staff'

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I'm newbie with django. I want to create an login, signup API so I find a solution on Internet. But it's not user my own User model, it use `django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser`. I don't need some field of `AbtractUser` so I give it `=none`.
Here is my models code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.

# class User(models.Model):
#     name = models.CharField(null=False,blank=False, max_length=512)
#     username = models.CharField(null=False,blank=False, max_length=512, unique=True)
#     email = models.EmailField(null=False,blank=False, max_length=512, unique=True)
#     password = models.CharField(null=False,blank=False, max_length=512)
#     status = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True, max_length=512)
#     role = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=1)
#     USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
#     REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
#     def __str__(self):
#         return self.username

class User(AbstractUser):
    last_login = None
    is_staff = None
    is_superuser = None
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
    name = models.CharField(null=False,blank=False, max_length=512)
    username = models.CharField(null=False,blank=False, max_length=512, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False,blank=False, max_length=512, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True, max_length=512)
    role = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=1)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)

 
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choices = models.JSONField(null=False, blank=False)
    answer = models.TextField(null=False,blank=False)
    level = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

But I can't login to my Django Admin with my Superuser. I create new superuser but I got an error `TypeError: User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_staff'`

My command to create superuser: `python manage.py createsuperuser`

I don't understand why my model can affect to my app superuser. Anyone can explain for me and give me some solution.

Here is my code in serializer:

```
from django.contrib.postgres import fields
from rest_framework import serializers
from app.models import User, Question, Category

class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=50, min_length=6)
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=50, min_length=6)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=150, write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'name','email', 'username', 'password', 'role']
    def validate(self, args):
        email = args.get('email', None)
        username = args.get('username', None)
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'email': ('Email already exists')})
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'username': ('Username already exists')})

        return super().validate(args)
  

    # def create(self, validated_data):
    #     return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'username', 'email', 'role']

class CategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'description']

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # category = CategorySerializer(read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['id', 'description', 'category', 'choices', 'answer', 'level']
```

Here is my code in views:

```
from django.db.models import query
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework import permissions
import uuid
from app.models import User, Category, Question
from app.serializers import UserSerializer, QuestionSerializer,  CategorySerializer, RegistrationSerializer

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

# Create your views here.

class RegistrationAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = RegistrationSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data = request.data)
        if(serializer.is_valid()):
            serializer.save()
            return Response({
                "RequestId": str(uuid.uuid4()),
                "Message": "User created successfully",
                
                "User": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
                )
        
        return Response({"Errors": serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class ListUsersAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request):
        listUser = User.objects.all()
        info = UserSerializer(listUser, many = True)
        return Response(data = info.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)

    # def post(self, request, format=None):
    #     serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    #     if serializer.is_valid():
    #         serializer.save()
    #         return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    #     return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class DetailUsersAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self,request, id):
        try: 
            user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=id)
            data = UserSerializer(user).data
            return Response(data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except:
            return Response("Error",status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def patch(self, request, id):
        user = get_object_or_404(Users, pk=id)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    queryset = Category.objects.all()

class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: You will need to define your own `UserManager` to register the user without making use of `is_staff`, `is_superuser`, etc. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends

Comment: how can I define my own `UserManager`. Your mind is that I create my own User model?

Comment: @HuynmMinhTri: well I asume that your `User` model is indeed the user model you use to create and authenticate users.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to [define your own `UserManager` [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends) to register the user without making use of `is_staff`, `is_superuser`, etc. This manager is used to create user objects. Since you have set fields like `is_staff`, `is_superuser`, etc. to `None`, these are no longer model fields.

Therefore you should implement your own user manager that will no longer try to set these fields in the user model. So this means it looks like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager

class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
```

This `UserManager` will not add `is_staff` and/or `is_superuser` to the fields that are used. You thus assign the `CutomUserManager` as `objects` manager to the user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # ⋮
    objects = CustomUserModel()
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm newbie with Django. Can I use my commented user model to create an Login, signup API using JWT?

Comment: @HuỳnhMinhTrí: no, a user model needs to have some extra attributes and methods to describe the username field, whether a user has a certain permission, etc. What is not working with your custom `User` model? Did you add the `CustomuserManager` as manager for your `User` model??

Comment: I don't know about how to create an custom `User` model. I just try to find a way to create an Login, signup API so I research on GG. I think I need an detail example to know more information about this. Can you help me?

Comment: Is that superuser of Django admin shared database table with `User` model I created?

Comment: @HuỳnhMinhTrí: you created your own user model. Since that model has no `is_superuser` and `is_admin`, it means that those fields should not be specified when creating a records for that model.

Comment: I don't know why it affect my superuser of Django admin? I just want to create my own user model. Why it not create a new table in DB for my user model?

Comment: @HuỳnhMinhTrí: it should create a new table, when you make migrations and migrate. Normally if you use the [`createsuperuser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#creating-superusers) command, it will create a user record for that table. Since you however have set `is_staff` and `is_admin` to `None`, it can no longer make a distinction between super users and "normal" users.

Comment: I use CustomUserModel for my model. But I still can't user create superuser for django admin. When I use `python manage.py createsuperuser`, it create a user in my user model. and I can't login to djangon admin `http://127.0.0.1:7000/admin/login/`. I got an error `Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.`.